# Update the Jsobject key of key value in Scala

Tags: scala, jsobject

I knew we can update the JsObject by key, however, how can I update the key of key in JsObject.

For example,

```
val queryText = (Json.parse(normalQuery) \"query" \"query_string" \"query").as[String]
```

I can get the string value, however, how can I update it?

```
  updatedJson ++ Json.obj("query/query_string/query" -> Json.toJson("new_test"))
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You should read the documentation on [JsPath](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsPath$json$). The method you're looking for is `JsPath.json.update`:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val baseJson = Json.obj("query" -> Json.obj("query_string" -> Json.obj("query" -> "old_value")))

val updater: Reads[JsObject] = __.json.update((__  \"query" \"query_string" \"query").json.put(JsString("new_value")))

val updated: JsResult[JsObject] = baseJson.transform(updater)
```

**Solution 2**

You can also add a field using `++` as you tried to do, but you need to define your object properly:

```
val overrider = Json.obj("query" -> Json.obj("query_string" -> Json.obj("query" -> "new_value")))

val badOverriden = baseJson ++ overrider
```

Actually, this does not work, because `++` is not recursive: it only overrides field at the top level of the JSON object. However, you can use `deepMerge` that does the same, recursively:

```
val overriden = baseJson deepMerge overrider
```